# VBA: copying specific cells from Excel into a table on Word and formatting the output

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, formatting

I'm not much of a coder, but I found a shell of source code online and have been tweaking it, despite no fully understanding what it's doing and now I've finally run into a problem. I don't have the slightest clue how to format the copied values. I'm sure there's a cleaner way of doing this in all and if it's possible for me to replicate it to get what I want, I'm all ears!

I want to take certain cells from an excel spread sheet and place them into a specifically styled and formatted table.

```
Option Explicit
Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\nicho\Final2\"
Dim wd As New Word.Application

Sub ExportButton()

Dim doc As Word.Document
wd.Visible = True

Dim J As String
Dim C As String
Dim F As String
Dim G As String
Dim E As String
Dim D As String

J = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("J2").Value   'value from sheet1
C = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2").Value
F = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F2").Value
G = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("G2").Value
E = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E2").Value
D = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2").Value

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "output.docx")
Copy2word "JField", J
Copy2word "CField", C
Copy2word "FField", F
Copy2word "GField", G
Copy2word "EField", E
Copy2word "DField", D

doc.Close

wd.Quit
'MsgBox "Created files in " & FilePath & "!"

End Sub
Sub Copy2word(BookMarkName As String, Text2Type As String)
'copy each cell to relevant Word bookmark
wd.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkName
wd.Selection.TypeText Text2Type
End Sub
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I've searched and haven't managed to find a solution with the code that I'm using.

Comment: So is your issue that you cannot find a way to format the text that you are copying to the Word document?

Answer (score 0):

When working in VBA, either in Excel or Word, it always advisable to avoid using the `Selection` object. Your Copy2Word routine can therefore be rewritten as below. This will allow you to add whatever formatting you need. You can get the essential code for that formatting by recording a macro in Word. Although the macro recorder will use the `Selection` object you will find that the same objects are available to the `Range`. You can also use the Object Browser and Intellisense to check that your code is valid.

Of course if the bookmarked locations are already properly formatted using styles you won't need to apply any formatting.

```
Sub Copy2word(targetDoc As Word.Document, BookMarkName As String, Text2Type As String)
  If targetDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(BookMarkName) Then
    With targetDoc.Bookmarks(BookMarkName).Range
      .text = Text2Type
      'add formatting code here
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```